# Send and receive data between multiple devices without using any server or external network

Tags: android, wifip2p

I am creating an app in which I want to add some information such that that whatever I add to my app that data should be visible to every user on their device.

But the problem is I can not use any server but I can use wifi, so is there any way to implement my idea?

I have seen something here related my idea.
[Demo app for WiFiP2P data sharing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901394/demo-app-for-wifip2p-data-sharing-in-android)

Comment: What you mean you don't want any server? as in a physical computer? or as in a software context like an apache web server? Am pretty sure your P2P idea still needs to have server/ client components.

Comment: You do still need a server.... *A peer-to-peer network is designed around the notion of equal peer nodes simultaneously functioning as **both "clients" and "servers"** to the other nodes on the network*... And WiFI (or Bluetooth) is considered an external network i.e. not `localhost`